# ERROR : Unknown error when installing the application "-24"

Tags: system-error, samsung-galaxy-note-3, troubleshooting

Every time I try to download an app called [icoron](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cfinc.iconkisekae) on my Galaxy note 3 an error message appears,
 `Unknown error when installing the application "-24`
Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `/data/data/`
2. search for your app `com.cfinc.iconkisekae` 
   (**If you wish to keep the information that it contains for the app, Recommend making a copy of it first.**)
3. Delete it
4. Install the application again.

DONE!!!!

[source](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1992241)

Comment: how do i go to /data/data/ ? in the browser?

Comment: Use File manager.